# Referenced external namespace crashes with local namespace

Tags: wpf, namespaces, user-controls, .net-assembly

I have a project called `This.Is.My.Project`, which contains a namespace `This.Is.My.Project.Namespace`. This namespace contains a UserControl class deriving from an external class of an external assembly in a namespace called `This.Is.Another.Project.Namespace`.

```
namespace This.Is.My.Project.Namespace {
   public partial class MyClass : This.Is.Another.Project.Namespace.ExternalClass {
     ...
   }
}
```

Now the compiler underlines the word `Another` and complains with the following message:

> The type or namespace name 'Another' does not exist in the namespace 'This.Is.My.Project.This.Is' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Obviously the compiler is looking for the external class in my local namespace because the first "sub" namespaces i.e. '`This.Is`' are equal. While actually it should be more seen like the project name being a single namespace instead of four nested ones, like so: `(I.Am.Not.Nested).ActualNamespace.MyClass` so in my case `(This.Is.My.Project).Namespace.MyClass`.

I can get rid of the code behind error by including `using This.Is.Another.Project.Namespace` but I'm running into the same problem on Xaml side where I cannot use any include.

```
<ext:ExternalClass x:Class="This.Is.My.Project.Namespace.MyClass"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                   xmlns:ext="http://schemas.external.com/winfx/2008/xaml/external">
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

I could rename the namespace manually from `This.Is.My.Project.Namespace` to `That.Is.My.Project.Namespace` and get rid of the error, but I'd like to keep the namespaces sounding as closest as possible as the user controls behave that closely. I'd even add the class to the external namespace if that was possible. Is there a way I can keep my namespace names and get rid of this error or do I have to rename my namespace?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the using in the code behind of that view, does it accept the namespace in the xaml then?

By the way, it is good practice to name different assemblies with different namespaces that best represents their meaning.

Comment: Well, this is supposed to be an "extension" to a DevExpress ComboBox. We have a custom DevExpress theme in our solution, into which I wanted to include this ComboBox. The DevExpress namespace is "DevExpress.Xpf.Editors" and our theme project is called "DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.NewTheme". Yes, true, it should actually not be part of the theme, as that is for styling purposes, but I did not want to create an extra project for this one control. And even if I did I would actually name the namespace exactly like the DevExpress one. The names in the post are just random samples.

Comment: And to your actual answer. I tried that already and got rid of the error in the code behind, but not in the Xaml, as already mentioned in the post.